# SVD - near-zero singular value

Tags: 3d, svd, cross-product, rigid-transformation, machine-precision

I have difficulties to handle singular values close to zero. My SVD implementation $A = U \Sigma V {}^{T}$ performs first an Eigen decomposition of the matrix $A {}^{T} A$. That is done with the [QR-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm), where the QR decomposition is computed with *Householder reflections*.

From the resulting Eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and Eigenvectors $v_i$, I compute the singular values 
$$
\Sigma {}{_{i,i}} = \sigma {}_i= \sqrt{\lambda_i}
$$
the right singular vectors 
$$
V_i = v_i
$$
and finally the left singular vectors
$$
U_i = \frac{Av_i}{\sigma {}_i}.
$$

In case $\sigma_i = 0$, the corresponding left singular vector is determined as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338584/singular-value-decomposition-with-zero-eigenvalue). As I work with double-percision, I do get small numbers instead of zero, which lead to an incorrect $U_i$. The situation is  actually worse, as the QR algorithm sometimes computes even very small negative Eigenvalues.

So far, I use a static thresholds to decide what is zero and also checks, such as testing in the end if $U$ is orthogonal. This appeared to be a lousy approach, because I have to adapt it regularly.

Does there exists a good concept or strategy to overcome these issues? Should the problem be tackled in the Eigen decomposition?

If it of interest: The whole code is [here](https://github.com/eidelen/EidLA) and the latest SVD problem arose when implementing [this paper](http://post.queensu.ca/~sdb2/PAPERS/PAMI-3DLS-1987.pdf).

Comment: Mathematically, it is true that one can work with $A^T A$ to get the SVD, but numerically this is a bad idea. There are better algorithms for the SVD that don't construct $A^T A$ or $A A^T$ but instead work with $A$ directly. You should look into them.

Comment: The method proposed by Golub and Kahan seems to be numerically more stable, even though it does not work on A directly. Would that be a good alternative or do you have a specific method in mind? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? I'd think that perhaps iterative methods would not run into these issues.

Comment: e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3990583/28743

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I implemented the Golub and Kahan approach. The floating-point zero problem is there explicitly stated. From an engineer's perspective, it is well explained in the book "Matrix Computations, Gene H. Golub".