# Iteratively solving (sparse) homogeneous linear systems

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, svd, sparse-matrices

Solving (sparse) non-homogeneous linear systems can be done iteratively, by using the [LSQR algorithm](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsqr/lsqr-toms82a.pdf) or similar. However, in the homogeneous case, we have $Ax =0$, where we typically want to find the non-zero solutions which is generally done by demanding a linear constraint on $x$, e.g. $|x|=1$. The method usually used to solve this constrained homogeneous system is by performing a singular value decomposition, and choosing the vector corresponding to the smallest singular value.

I'm looking for an iterative equivalent of LSQR that may be applied to sparse rectangular systems. LSQR does not seem appropriate, as it's stages implicitly assume $|b|\neq0$. Is anyone aware of such a method or can think of a method to modify LSQR appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **LSQR**, by setting $b$, very close to zero (not exactly zero), which prevents, the trivial solution $(x = 0)$, In practice, it's a quite good approximation.

$Ax = \varepsilon$ ,

where $\varepsilon \approx 0$

ex. $\varepsilon = 10^{-7}$

In case of your application, requires an exact zero solution, then you might need to involve $m$ inequality constraints, $x > 0$, which could be solved easily using Lagrangian multipliers.

Comment: LSQR seems to be designed against that - it has an update step of $b/|b|$, which would seem to be unstable if $|b|$ was too small. This definitely wouldn't work if we had $b$ identically zero.

Comment: So, I'll give this a try to see if this gives the desired accuracy without blowing up, but I'm convinced there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through [this paper](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Estoledo/Bib/Pubs/GotsmanToledo.pdf), it gives a number of methods. The most straight forward seems to be the following algorithm:

1. Start with a random solution $x_0$
2. Break $A$ into it's QR decomposition, where Q is of size $m\times n$, and $R$ is upper diagonal
3. Solve via backwards substitution:
   $$R^Tw = x_{t-1}/|x_{t-1}|$$
   $$R x_t = w$$
4. Iterate until convergence